# Kinect Xbox360 new model 1473 has problems... (example : serial number, soundcard)

Tags: ros, kinect, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

Some of you may have noticed, but there are different version of Kinect Xbox360. As I believe some of you will make some comment to that, I want to precise the different models of Kinect :

- Kinect for Windows
- Kinect Xbox360, old model number 1414
- Kinect Xbox360, new model number 1473

You can see the version on the back of the kinect, as shown in [this thread](http://www.pcl-users.org/new-kinect-1473-td4024909.html). The last two kinect have some minor changes, as you can see on this "lsusb -v" :

(you can go to the bottom, where a string comparison shows the differences)

**Model 1414 :**

```
    Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:02c2 Microsoft Corp. 
    Device Descriptor:
      bLength                18
      bDescriptorType         1
      bcdUSB               2.00
      bDeviceClass            9 Hub
      bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
      bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
      bMaxPacketSize0        64
      idVendor           0x045e Microsoft Corp.
      idProduct          0x02c2 
      bcdDevice            0.01
      iManufacturer           0 
      iProduct                0 
      iSerial                 0 
      bNumConfigurations      1
      Configuration Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         2
        wTotalLength           25
        bNumInterfaces          1
        bConfigurationValue     1
        iConfiguration          0 
        bmAttributes         0xe0
          Self Powered
          Remote Wakeup
        MaxPower                2mA
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        0
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           1
          bInterfaceClass      Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:078c Microsoft Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x045e Microsoft Corp.
  idProduct          0x078c 
  bcdDevice            1.11
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           34
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               70mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              5 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      65
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              24

Bus 003 Device 018: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x045e Microsoft Corp.
  idProduct          0x02ad Xbox NUI Audio
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 Microsoft
  iProduct                2 Xbox NUI Audio
  iSerial                 4 A44866C05801052A
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           46
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes           13
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Synchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x020c  1x 524 bytes
        bInterval               5
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes           13
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Synchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x004c  1x 76 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 003 Device 017: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x045e Microsoft Corp.
  idProduct          0x02b0 Xbox NUI Motor
  bcdDevice            1.05
  iManufacturer           1 Microsoft
  iProduct                2 Xbox NUI Motor
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           18
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)

Bus 003 Device 019: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x045e Microsoft Corp.
  idProduct          0x02ae Xbox NUI Camera
  bcdDevice            1.0b
  iManufacturer           2 Microsoft
  iProduct                1 Xbox NUI Camera
  iSerial                 3 A00366906370052A
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower               16mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0bc0  2x 960 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0bc0  2x 960 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

**Model 1473 :**

```
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 045e:02c2 Microsoft Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x045e Microsoft Corp.
  idProduct          0x02c2 
  bcdDevice            0.01
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           25
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                2mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0001  1x 1 bytes
        bInterval              12

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:078c Microsoft Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x045e Microsoft Corp.
  idProduct          0x078c 
  bcdDevice            1.11
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           34
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               70mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              5 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      65
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              24

Bus 003 Device 012: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x045e Microsoft Corp.
  idProduct          0x02ad Xbox NUI Audio
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 Microsoft
  iProduct                2 Xbox Kinect Audio, © 2011 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
  iSerial                 3 A70771X06860237A
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           46
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              4 Config
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes           13
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Synchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x020c  1x 524 bytes
        bInterval               5
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes           13
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Synchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x004c  1x 76 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 003 Device 015: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x045e Microsoft Corp.
  idProduct          0x02ae Xbox NUI Camera
  bcdDevice            2.05
  iManufacturer           2 Microsoft
  iProduct                1 Xbox NUI Camera
  iSerial                 3 0000000000000000
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower               16mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0bc0  2x 960 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0bc0  2x 960 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Differences between the two files (using a string comparator), where n-xx-yy refers to new model, from line xx to line yy, and o-xx-yy is for old model from line xx to line yy :

```
 n-1-48 : the first bloc doesn't exist for the old kinect
 o-59 n-107 : audio device number is different
 o-72 n-120 : iProduct is different (2 Xbox NUI Audio  // 2 Xbox Kinect Audio, © 2011 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.)
 o-73 n-121 : iSerial is different
 o-94 n-142 : iInterface is different (0 // 4 Config)
 o-147-184 : the motor bloc doesn't exist in the new kinect 
 o-197 n-206 : bcdDevice different ( 1.0b // 2.05)
 o-200 n-209 : iSerial is different
```

And that's all !! My problem is that **hark-ros** doesn't recognize the kinect audio anymore... Even by doing

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

I have no kinect soundcard recognized. I tried again with an old model (1414) and it works...

Anyone has any idea ?

Thank you,

Bests regards,

Stéphane

Ps : I put as much information as possible, in order to document the problem with all I know

Ps 2 : I would be interested to know if anyone had any problem when passing from model 1414 to 1473 (it seems some people had driver problems related to that, when reading the thread mentioned on top of this post)

[EDIT] : wrong copy-paste in the first subject submission, corrected to show the differences.

[EDIT 2] : I didn't saw this earlier, but the new model 1473 of kinect doesn't have a serial number anymore !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61542/kinect-xbox360-new-model-1473-has-problems...-(example-:-serial-number,-soundcard)/) by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1304 on 2013-04-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-05-24**:
The old kiniect shows up as an audio device in /proc/asound/cards but the new one doesn't? Sounds like a kernel/driver problem; outside of ROS.

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-05-29**:
You are right, it is a driver issue. However, itsn't solved neither for Avin2 drivers (which have video, but no audio neither serial video number), neither libfreekinect (nothing for this one). Good luck with the new kinects guys....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try using your device with OpenNI2 (https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni2_camera)?

They added support for more devices. See this related question: http://answers.ros.org/question/54747/primesense-carmine-doesnt-work-but-asus-xtion-does-openni-launch-devices-connected-but-not-found/.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-09-10**:
no, because ROS is not working with openNI2 for now... on the first link you gave, they say that it doesn't work with kinect. I will have it tested anyway, just in case :-)
Thanks for the links.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-10**:
Great you pointed that out. I actually believe I tested it with the Kinect, but that was weeks ago. Please let us know, how your tests went.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-15**:
Unfortunately, they are right. OpenNI2 doesn't work with the Kinect - apparently [due to licensing issues](http://cupofpixel.blogspot.kr/2013/04/how-to-use-openni-2-nite-2-kinect-on.html) The [freenect_stack](https://github.com/ros-drivers/freenect_stack) seems the way to go for the Kinect.

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-09-15**:
After some testing,OpenNI2 can work with kinects.Steps : 1) install dependencie freenect 2) install openni2.2 3) install nite 2.2 4) download https://github.com/piedar/OpenNI2-FreenectDriver 5) build freenect driver (./waf configure build) 6) copy .so file in all Drivers folders (in openni and nite)